# Update column in table with concat option and make it 2 digits

Tags: mysql

I want to update a column in my table with concat of 2 fields.
 It works fine, but i want to append 0 to one of the field if its not 2 digits because i want my month data to be 2 digits long.
 What i have in months column is single digit data.

```
update employee_status set year_month = concat(year,month);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want [lpad](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad)

```
update employee_status set year_month = concat(year, lpad(month, 2, '0'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
update employee_status set year_month = concat(year, lpad(month,2,'0'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
update employee_status set year_month = concat(year, (if(length(month)) == 2, month, concat(0,month)));
```